# Optimization with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: matlab, optimization, symbols, integral

I have an optimization problem which I have to solve using Lagrange multipliers.
I have the following code:

```
clear all
clc
p = @(r,sig) (r./sig.^2) .* exp(-r.^2/2*(sig.^2));
sig = 1;
Pa = 1;
Pc = 20;
a = 0.5;
b = 1;
phi = @(h_AB,h_AC,h_CB) abs(h_AB).^2 +((b .* a.^2*abs(h_AC).^2 .* abs(h_CB).^2)
    .* Pc ./ (1 + b * a .^2 .* abs(h_CB) .^2 * Pc));
f1 = @(h_AB,h_AC,h_CB) .5*log((1+phi(h_AB,h_AC,h_CB)*Pa)/(1+abs(h_AC).^2*Pa));
f2 = @(h_AB,h_AC,h_CB) f1(h_AB,h_AC,h_CB) .* p(h_AB,sig) .* p(h_AC,sig).*  (h_CB,sig);
q = integral3(f2,-inf,inf,-inf,inf,-inf,inf);
```

The constant `b` that I have defined should be a variable (`q` be a function of `b`), so that I would find `e = jacobian(q,[b]);` in the next step.

The problem is that I can't define `b` as symbolic while other functions are not symbolic and when I define all the functions in symbolic form, I get out of memory solving `e = jacobian(q,[b]);`

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a hint that might save you lots of time: use the right tools for the right job. If you want symbolics use Mathematica, MATLAB is particularly unsuitable for that.

Comment: Thank you but i never worked with Mathematica